# Routers not working in prod mode using Angular 2 and Apache

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, deployment, router

I'm having a problem when deplsy an angular4 app on prodution mode. I'm following the steps indicated on https://angular.io/guide/deployment. The directory that apache is setting to is the folder dist from my project. Here are the highlights of my project:

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {  path: 'politica-privacidade', component: PoliticaPrivacidadeComponent },
        {  path: '', component: PaginaInicialComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            PaginaInicialModule,
            PoliticaPrivacidadeModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
        ],
        providers: [],
        bootstrap: [
            AppComponent
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

**Apache conf file**

```
<VirtualHost 80.241.208.103:80>
    ServerName coreografando.com.br
    ServerAlias www.coreografando.com.br
    ServerAdmin braulio@braulioti.com.br
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/coreografando/dist"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/coreografando/cgi-bin/"


    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup apache apache
        suPHP_ConfigPath /var/www/coreografando/dist
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/var/www/coreografando/dist">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

for deploy I'm using the command line:

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: What does "Routers not working in prod mode" mean? is it throwing any errors? What's the behavior of it?

Comment: in this case /politica-privacidade results in 404

Comment: I suppose the root path does work then, right? Does it result in 404 when you try to init the page through the subroute (by refreshing this path in the browser for example) or aren't you able to call this route at all, even through angulars navigation?

Comment: Exactly. But in development mode I don't have a problem with the subroutes. I believe it's the way I'm doing deploy or some configuration in apache

Comment: But in dev mode you are not using an apache server, right?

Comment: No... in dev mode I use "ng serve"

Comment: In this case, your index.html is being properly displayed by its route `path: ''` or by 404 route at Apache's setup? `RewriteRule ^ /index.html`

Comment: The subrouters displaying 404, but the main page index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has nothing to do with how you build your app, but rather how your server handles incoming routes. I think `ng serve` just takes all requests and tunnels them to the index.html where the angular router can take of the requested path. Your current apache server does something else. In my opinion your .htaccess file is just not working properly, although I'm not really familiar with it.

The angular-seed project has a short tutorial on their [github wiki](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2) on how to deploy an angular build to an apache server. Here's how their .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For the rest of the stuff that is necessary you should checkout their tutorial, it's not that long. I personally think your build process should be fine and the problem is on the apache side.

### Edit

One additional important thing, the apache configuration should have `AllowOverride all` enabled for the directory where the Angular2 app is served. Here's what the tutorial says about it:

> Also for the `rewrite` module to work, the apache configuration should
>   have AllowOverride all enabled for the directory where the Angular2
>   app is served. In the default cause this be done as following:
>
> Open the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` Then add the
>   following piece of code inside the `VirtualHost` block (assuming the
>   Angular2 app is served from `/var/www/html`)

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was not with the settings of the .htaccess file and yes in the conf file. was missing "AllowOverride All". Thanks for their tutorial

Comment: ah yeah, I read about it, but didn't really understand what this meant. Glad it helped you fix your problem though. I'm gonna update my answer for future references